# Plot a Linechart using an ascending number as x-Axis value instead of a time-series

Tags: grafana

I need to display a chart plotted by an ascending number (a build number) instead of a timeseries.

The goal is pretty similar to this Jenkins JUnit report:

[image: Example Linechart]

It would be nice to have a solution that works also for the status history (buildnumber instead of timeseries):

[image: Example Statushistory]

As datebase mssql is used.

How to configure the x-Axis that the number is used and every entry takes up the same amount of space (like shown in the JUnit image #1, #22, #36)